# How to know binary string or ascii string in python

Tags: python, binary

I have a string variable for mac address.
it can be binary - '\x00\x04\x96\x82Q\xbb' or ascii - 'c8:be:19:c6:a0:e0'. If it is binary i need to convert it to ascii string with **b2a_hex** function. Is it possible to know what type of string i am having now?

Answer (score 0):

hex(number) -> string

Return the hexadecimal representation of an integer or long integer.

//this function use to get decimal number and then using that decimal get hexadecimal number.

```
>>int('010110', 2)
22
>>> hex(int('010110', 2))
'0x16'
>>> 

>>> hex(int('0000010010001101', 2))
'0x48d'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the length. If it's 6 then you have binary, if it's bigger then it's text.

```
if len(s) <= 6:
    s = binascii.b2a_hex(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple `find`.If `string.find(":") == -1` it is binary else it is ascii.

Answer (score -1):

Mac address is 48 bits long.

If a Mac address is presented in binary, it will take 6 bytes.( 8bit(1Byte)*6=46bits)

If a Mac address is presented in ascii, it will take 17 ASCII characters (17 bites).

So, if the data is 6 bytes, it may contain Mac address in binary.
if the data is 17 bytes or more, it may contain Mac address in ASCII.